# Inner divs not rendered in React Functional component

Tags: reactjs

I can't figure out why my inner divs are not being rendered, so I am hoping someone can help point out the problem.

```js
const avatarColors = [
    '#labc9c',
    '#2ecc71',
    '#607d8b',
    '#a20c0cc',
    '#cddc39',
    '#009688',
    '#fba4b4',
    '#ffd54f',
    '#ff5e00'
]

export const AvatarColorMenu = () =>    
    <div className='avatarColorMenuContainer'>
    { avatarColors.map(color => {
        <div key={color} style={{backgroundColor: {color}}}>C</div>
    })}
    </div>

export default AvatarColorMenu
```

```css
.avatarColorMenuContainer {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 75px 75px 75px;
  background-color: #444;
  grid-gap: 5px;
}

.avatarColorMenuContainer > div {
  width: 75px; 
  height: 75px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

The result renders as:

```js
<div className='avatarColorMenuContainer'></div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two issues here:

1. wrap the return value in parenthesis
2. either explicitly `return` inside `map(..)`, or wrap the return value with parenthesis, not curly braces.

```js
const AvatarColorMenu = () => (
  <div className='avatarColorMenuContainer'>
    { avatarColors.map((color) => (
      <div key={color} style={{backgroundColor: {color}}}>C</div>
    ))}
  </div>
);
```

Answer (score 1):

You missing return inside map()

Also, change {color} to color

For example:

```
{avatarColors.map(color => {
   return (<div key={color} style={{ backgroundColor: color }}>C</div>)
})}
```

Answer (score 1):

Arrow function(higher order) expects a return statement; Because javascript interprets semi-colon at the end of a line! That way it has added a semi-colon at the end of this line: ( export const AvatarColorMenu = () => )

```
export const AvatarColorMenu = () =>    
    <div className='avatarColorMenuContainer'>
    { avatarColors.map(color => {
        return <div key={color} style={{backgroundColor: {color}}}>C</div>
    })}
    </div>
```

Or if you don't want a return statement then put it like below(In one line)

```
export const AvatarColorMenu = () => <div className='avatarColorMenuContainer'> { avatarColors.map(color => <div key={color} style={{backgroundColor: {color}}}>C</div>)} </div>
```